# How to group mutiple rows with First Main Column using MUI DataGrid react JS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, datatable, material-ui, datagrid

[image: Reference]

How can I create a table using Materil UI DataGrid to construct the columns and rows shown in the image?

I am able to create normal table with datagrib but having trouble making multiple sub rows with the first column.

Much appriciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `renderCell` prop in the DataGrid columns object to choose how you wish to render the data for each column. `renderCell` is a method which allows you to customise how to render your data. So imagine I have a `DataGrid` comprising of information related to countries. If I have a column called Seasonal Temperatures, and I want to render a sub row for each season, I could do something like this in the `columns` array which is passed to the `DataGrid`. Notice that I use MUI `Grid` to make each sub row but you could use other means and add whatever components you wanted to your subrow (buttons, icons, input etc...):

```
    const columns = [
    {
      field: "seasonalTemperatures",
      headerName: "Seasonal Temperatures",
      renderCell: ({ row }) => {
        return (
          <Grid container>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography>{row.seasonalTemperatures.summer}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography>{row.seasonalTemperatures.winter}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography>{row.seasonalTemperatures.spring}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={12}>
              <Typography>{row.seasonalTemperatures.autumn}</Typography>
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        );
      },
    },
    // more columns
]
```

Also remember to adjust the row height of your `DataGrid` accordingly via the `rowHeight` prop, as the default height will probably not be high enough for multiple sub rows.

You can put whatever you like in RenderCell. To make it similar to your screenshot above, I have added a switch component and datepicker, my field, now called `details`, looks like this:

```
{
    field: "details",
    headerName: "Details",
    width: 500,
    editable: false,
    renderCell: ({ row }) => {
      return (
        <Grid container rowSpacing={3}>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography variant="h5">{row.details.productNo}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            <Typography>{row.details.description1}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container alignItems="center">
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <Typography>{row.details.description2}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={6}>
              <DatePickerOpenTo />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
          <Grid container alignItems="center">
            <Grid item xs>
              <Typography>{row.details.toggleText}</Typography>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item>
              <Switch />
            </Grid>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      );
    }
  },
```

Which gives a column like this:

[image: Data Grid Screenshot]

I have also put the code on CodeSandbox so you can see what it looks like and play around with it. Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-sky-j9ndvc?file=/src/App.js:313-1269)

Comment: Well, I tried the above code, but it isn't working as expected; if you look at the sample screenshot, it shows an entirely different requirement; I appreciate your response.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I've updated my answer, provided code which produces the rows in your screenshot and provided a link to codesandbox where you can see the datagrid live and play around with the code. I hope this helps :-)

Comment: Thank you for the corrected code; I hope you understood my question. I'll explain once again...If you look at the screenshot, you'll note that multiple rows are grouped together in the first column; if you could adjust your code to reflect this, it would be quite useful.

Comment: I believe my code did create four sub-rows within the column like in your screenshot, so I am not quite sure what your requirements are, maybe you could further elaborate?